# Multiple choice ListView and SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, sharedpreferences

I want to save the state of a multiple choice listview checkbox's. I have the following layout.

[image]

What i want to do is to save the state of, for instance, "test1 and test3" and when i return to this activity this checkboxs are checked. I'm using shared preferences. I have the following code.

This loads my list:

```
mList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListViewTarefas);      
    final TarefaDbAdapter db = new TarefaDbAdapter(this);
    db.open();  
    data = db.getAllTarefas(getIntent().getExtras().get("nomeUtilizadorTarefa").toString());
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,data);
    mList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    mList.setAdapter(adapter);
    LoadSelections();
```

and this is the following code loads and saves the state of the checkboxs (supposedly).

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // always handle the onPause to make sure selections are saved if user clicks back button
    SaveSelections();
    super.onPause();
}

private void ClearSelections() {
    // user has clicked clear button so uncheck all the items
    int count = this.mList.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        this.mList.setItemChecked(i, false);
    }
    // also clear the saved selections
    SaveSelections();
}

private void LoadSelections() {
    // if the selections were previously saved load them
    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settingsActivity.contains(data.toString())) {
        String savedItems = settingsActivity.getString(data.toString(), "");
        this.data.addAll(Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(",")));
        int count = this.mList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String currentItem = (String) this.mList.getAdapter().getItem(i);
            if (this.data.contains(currentItem)) {
                this.mList.setItemChecked(i, true);
            }
        }
    }
}


private void SaveSelections() {
    // save the selections in the shared preference in private mode for the user
    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = settingsActivity.edit();
    String savedItems = getSavedItems();
    prefEditor.putString(data.toString(), savedItems);
    prefEditor.commit();
}


private String getSavedItems() {
    String savedItems = "";
    int count = this.mList.getAdapter().getCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (this.mList.isItemChecked(i)) {
            if (savedItems.length() > 0) {
                savedItems += "," + this.mList.getItemAtPosition(i);
            } else {
                savedItems += this.mList.getItemAtPosition(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return savedItems;
}
```

Than i load the SaveSelections and Clear Selections methods in buttons.

The problem is that this isn't working. can somebody help me please?

My regards.

Comment: Did you try to put some logs in your code? For example, does settingsActivity.contains(data.toString()) return true? And what String do you get via getString() method?

Comment: Hi. The problem is that when i enter again in this activity, i adds more values than those that existed and it sets all checkbox true.

Comment: Then you should overwrite the existing values, means you should store them under the existing key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into a similar issue recently. It's likely because items in the ListView are being recycled (properties and all). You should explicitly set the ones that were NOT saved to the unchecked state.

**EDIT:**
Also, though I may be misunderstanding, I don't think you should be adding your saved strings to "data" because that's what your adapter is using to generate your list, isn't it?

Try this:

```
private void LoadSelections() {
    // if the selections were previously saved load them
    SharedPreferences settingsActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    if (settingsActivity.contains(data.toString())) {
        String savedItems = settingsActivity.getString(data.toString(), "");
        ArrayList<String> savedItemsList = (ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList(savedItems.split(","));
        int count = this.mList.getAdapter().getCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            String currentItem = (String) this.mList.getAdapter().getItem(i);
            if (savedItemList.contains(currentItem)) {
                this.mList.setItemChecked(i, true);
            } else {
                this.mList.setItemChecked(i, false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it works for you!

Comment: Hi derrik. Thanks for your atention. I use your code but when i start the activity again, all checkbox's are checked. I don't know why. :s

Comment: @fegol1985 Sorry about that! I just modified my answer. Could you give it a try? It's hard for me to test this without seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: i can send you my class if you give me your email. I can't figure it out by myself. I tried everything i know... my regards

Comment: @fegol1985 Sounds good. You can send it to derrikc at gmail. If I get it working, I'll update my answer.